# getting error while building the yocto after change gstreamer version from 1.20.6 to 1.22.4

Tags: ubuntu, yocto, libsoup

getting "libsoup" error while triggering the yocto build after upgrade the gstreamer version from 1.20.6 to 1.20.0.

ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'libsoup' (but /home/kasevaddi/local_build/poky/../meta-zeiss-meditec/meta-zeiss-software/recipes-backport/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good_1.20.0.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it). Close matches:
liboop
libsoc
libsoup-2.4
NOTE: Runtime target 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-good' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['gstreamer1.0-plugins-good', 'libsoup']
ERROR: Required build target 'zeiss-core-image-minimal' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['zeiss-core-image-minimal', 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-good', 'libsoup']

Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Have you changed the `PACKAGECONFIG_SOUP` variable during the update? In any case, if you don't want to use libsoup, you can set this variable to be empty in a bbappend, it supposed to remove this dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added PACKAGECONFIG_SOUP = " libsoup" in the plugins_good.bbappend file. after update the .bbappend file libsoup issue has been gone. but again i am facing different ERROR. i will let you know regarding error.

Comment: If you want to use libsoup, the value of this variable should be `soup2` or `soup3` (depending on the version you want to use). `libsoup` itself is part of poky, so it supposed to find it, unless your poky repo is badly damaged for some reason.

Comment: ERROR: gstreamer1.0-1.22.4-r0 do_configure: meson failed ERROR: gstreamer1.0-1.22.4-r0 do_configure: Execution of '/home/kasevaddi/local_build/build/tmp/work/dbfp5-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0/1.22.4-r0/temp/run.do_configure.5212' failed with exit code 1: The Meson build system Version: 0.59.1. here i changed the meson version from 0.59.1 to 0.62.0, as per error log. after change the meason version getting same error.